# Pre-requisites & Procedure to install selenium tool on Windows 7 Operating system?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to Install Selenium open source tool in my pc ( windows 7 OS)

I would like to know the  procedure as well as per-requisities .

Comment: What have you tried so far, what documents did you refer to, what happened after you did a search ?

Comment: Hi @Venkat, I'm afraid this question is off-topic. As it's pretty old, I hope you figured it out somehow!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that could be easily found in the Selenium docs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried browsing the [Selenium website?](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) There is documentation (installation instructions etc) that will help you get started. Also, perusing this site will help (searching for selenium questions/answers) as many people would've asked a similar question before.